# How can I append an array to a table element if I select the table with querySelector & getElementById?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
const trElements = document.querySelector("#removeTest").tBodies[0].children

const trArray = Array.from(trElements)
const newOne2 = $("#removeTest2")

newOne2.append(trArray)
```

```css
#removeTest { 
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    height: 100px;
    width:300px;
}
#removeTest2 { 
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>

<table id="removeTest">
    <tr>
        <td>test1</td>
        <td>test1</td>
        <td>test1</td>
        <td>test1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>test2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test3</td>
        <td>test3</td>
        <td>test3</td>
        <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test4</td>
        <td>test4</td>
        <td>test4</td>
        <td>test4</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="removeTest2">


</table>
```

Here, I am appending the array of `tr`s directly into the `removeTest2` by selecting it with jQuery. It works perfectly.

However...

```js
const trElements = document.querySelector("#removeTest").tBodies[0].children

const trArray = Array.from(trElements)

const newOne = document.querySelector("#removeTest2");
newOne.append(trArray)
```

```css
#removeTest { 
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    height: 100px;
    width:300px;
}
#removeTest2 { 
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid red;
    height: 100px;
    width:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>

<table id="removeTest">
    <tr>
        <td>test1</td>
        <td>test1</td>
        <td>test1</td>
        <td>test1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>test2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test3</td>
        <td>test3</td>
        <td>test3</td>
        <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test4</td>
        <td>test4</td>
        <td>test4</td>
        <td>test4</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="removeTest2">


</table>
```

If I do the same but with vanilla JS, I get this:

```
[object HTMLTableRowElement],[object HTMLTableRowElement],[object HTMLTableRowElement],[object HTMLTableRowElement]
```

Only objects. Why? What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use jQuery selector, it returns `JQuery` object, which has it's own `append()` function - documented [here](https://api.jquery.com/append/).

When you use native browser selector, return object is of type `Element`, which has it's own `append()` function, behaving slightly differently and documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append).

So for the `Element.append()` you have to spread the array, like this:

```
myElement.append(...myArray);
```

Otherwize, if array is passed without spread, it's threated as a single item and is converted to string internally, using `myArray.toString()`.

Markup of your table becomes:

```html
<table id="removeTest2">
    [object HTMLTableRowElement],[object HTMLTableRowElement],[object HTMLTableRowElement],[object HTMLTableRowElement]
</table>
```

If you use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), you'll get correct result (table with table rows):

```js
const trElements = document.querySelector("#removeTest").tBodies[0].children

const trArray = Array.from(trElements)

const newOne = document.querySelector("#removeTest2");
newOne.append(...trArray)
```

```css
#removeTest { 
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    height: 100px;
    width:300px;
}
#removeTest2 { 
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid red;
    height: 100px;
    width:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>

<table id="removeTest">
    <tr>
        <td>test1</td>
        <td>test1</td>
        <td>test1</td>
        <td>test1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>test2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test3</td>
        <td>test3</td>
        <td>test3</td>
        <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test4</td>
        <td>test4</td>
        <td>test4</td>
        <td>test4</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="removeTest2">


</table>
```

Comment: If it's converted to text, then why is it not appended as text? If I have an array with a bunch of string values, like `honda, mazda, laptop`, and `append()` that array to an element, It works. It gets appended as single string.

Comment: By the way, with the rest parameters `...`, I am just appending the values of the array, right? Rest parameter resolves the array, correct?

Comment: It is appended as a text (`"[object HTMLTableRowElement],..."`). Inspect the markup of the table "removeTest2" in you example. Spread operator `...` does not append values to an array, it expands/extracts them, like `.append(trArray[0], trArray[1], trArray[2]...)`

Comment: Why does it work with jQuery then? When I use jQuery to select the element, I don't have to use the spread operator for the array, I can just append the array, and it works. Why?

Comment: Because jQuery selector returns `JQuery` object, while native selector returns `Element` object. So `Element.append(...)` vs `JQuery.append(...)`. It's two different functions, implemented in a different way.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

[$.append (JQuery)](https://api.jquery.com/append/) is different from [Element.append (vanilla DOM)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append)

You can spread the elements to append them like JQuery does internally.

```js
const trElements = document.querySelector("#removeTest").tBodies[0].children;

const newOne = document.querySelector("#removeTest2");
newOne.append(...trElements);
```

```css
#removeTest { 
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    height: 100px;
    width:300px;
}
#removeTest2 { 
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid red;
    height: 100px;
    width:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>

<table id="removeTest">
    <tr>
        <td>test1</td>
        <td>test1</td>
        <td>test1</td>
        <td>test1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>test2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test3</td>
        <td>test3</td>
        <td>test3</td>
        <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test4</td>
        <td>test4</td>
        <td>test4</td>
        <td>test4</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="removeTest2">


</table>
```